# flutter firebase wire operation

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

This is my code for add new address in firebase realtime database

```
Future<bool> addAddress(Address adr)async{
  database = FirebaseDatabase(app: app);
await  database
          .reference()
          .child(table_name).child(uid)
          .set(adr).then((onValue){

            print("adress add complected");
            return true;
          }).catchError((onError){
             print("adress add failed $uid");
            print(onError);
            return false;
          });
}
```

but it returning error

> Invalid argument: Instance of 'Address'

Where is i am doging wrong ?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the top level of your `addAddress` method. So at the least (and possibly unrelated to the error), you'll need to `return await database`.

Answer (score 1):

Your input for set() has to be type Map, so you have to do something like this:

```
Future<bool> addAddress(Address adr)async{
        database = FirebaseDatabase(app: app);
        await  database
          .reference()
          .child(table_name).child(uid)
          .set({
            "country": adr.count,
            "state": adr.state,
            "city": adr.city,
          }).then((onValue){

            print("adress add complected");
            return true;
          }).catchError((onError){
             print("adress add failed $uid");
            print(onError);
            return false;
          });
}
```

Comment: I understand that but I need an easy solution like java json

Comment: Unfortunately, looking at the [API documentation and implementation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/set.html) that doesn't seem to be available in Flutter.